# Can we build android from external Hard Disk

Tags: android, build, external, hard-drive

I have less space in my Laptop.. So i am thinking to build android source code from external Hard Disk, which has 1TB of space.. Is it possible to build android source from External HDD.

Comment: If you have eclipse and android SDK in your external hard disk, doesn't matter and of course hard disk must be kept connected to the laptop ;)

Comment: Are you talking about android os source code build, right?

Comment: @Fahim - it's not quite that simple.  Also, Eclipse has no role in building android itself, rather it is a (now deprecated, but still common) environment for building apps which run under Android.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes, you can, however there are some issues to keep in mind:

- The hard disk probably must have a unix-like filesystem.  Your typical off-the-shelf storage brick probably comes formatted with NTFS or even some variation of FAT.
- It probably needs to be mounted without a -noexec flag, as early stages may (?) build tools that need to run later.  Also, your user needs to have write access to it.
- It's probably going to be slower building this way, since an everyday USB interface will likely have lower bandwidth than a good local drive.  Also, chances are your remote drive is 5400 RPM and not 7200.

That said, I have seen it recommended to build from sources on one drive, to an output directory on another (with both being local to the same machine), to avoid rapid seeking back and forth between source locations and output locations.  How true this actually is in a multithreaded build on a modern mutli-core system may be an interesting question.

If you really want to build Android (or re-build substantial portions of it) on your laptop frequently, considering upgrading it to a 1TB 7200 RPM drive (or if you can afford a large one and to put wear on it, an SSD).  If you only plan to do it once or twice and can leave it running overnight with decent airflow, then if you set the external drive up right you might as well just do that.

Comment: Also cache portion required huge amount of memory.